# On Ubuntu Server 18.04, can't get my domain to resolve unless www is used

Tags: internet, dns, www

I can't get pangeawerks.com to resolve but www.pangeawerks.com works great

I pinged the domain and here are the results:

```
karmacomposer@PANGEAVERSE:~$ ping pangeawerks.com
ping: pangeawerks.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

karmacomposer@PANGEAVERSE:~$ ping www.pangeawerks.com
PING www.pangeawerks.com(::1 (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ::1 (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from ::1 (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from ::1 (::1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from ::1 (::1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from ::1 (::1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms

--- www.pangeawerks.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4094ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.039/0.047/0.053/0.010 ms
```

I know it has to do with my DNS server (it's our own server here at my office, so not a host).

If anyone could help me get this working, it's causing me a lot of grief.

Thank you.

Mike

Comment: Question is not `Ubuntu` related but you have my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with DNS resolution.

```
dig pangeawerks.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-RedHat-9.11.3-12.fc28 <<>> pangeawerks.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 39391
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pangeawerks.com.       IN  A

;; Query time: 462 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 18 21:02:31 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

and

```
dig www.pangeawerks.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-RedHat-9.11.3-12.fc28 <<>> www.pangeawerks.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36304
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.pangeawerks.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.pangeawerks.com.    604424  IN  A   72.31.51.26

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 18 21:02:49 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53
```

Create fallowing records. First `A` record to point to you `ip`

```
pangeawerks.com     A     72.31.51.26
```

After that make `CNAME` record to *connect* `www` with hostname

```
www.pangeawerks.com   CNAME    pangeawerks.com
```

This records must be make on Authority DNS server.

Here are the current results of dig pangeawerks.com:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> pangeawerks.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 57836
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 79cc3057e00d2854be8b8e965b4f92ce402e52c17af6f46e (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pangeawerks.com.               IN      A

;; Query time: 405 msec
;; SERVER: 72.31.51.26#53(72.31.51.26)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 18 15:19:42 EDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 72
```

Here is the contents of my zone file for pangeawerks.com.db:

```
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     pangeawerks.com. PANGEAVERSE.pangeawerks.com. (
                         33         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.
@       IN      A       72.31.51.26
@       IN      AAAA    ::1

;Name Server Information
@       IN      NS      PANGEAVERSE.pangeawerks.com.

;IP address of Your Domain Name Server(DNS)
pangeawerks.com  A      73.31.51.26

;Mail Server MX (Mail exchanger) Record
pangeawerks.com. IN  MX  10  mail.pangeawerks.com.

;A Record for Host names
www     IN       A       72.31.51.26
mail    IN       A       72.31.51.30

;CNAME Record
ftp     IN      CNAME    www.pangeawerks.com.
www.pangeawerks.com     CNAME   pangeawerks.com.
```

And here is the reverse lookup file db.72:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     pangeawerks.com. PANGEAVERSE.pangeawerks.com. (
                          6         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@          IN      NS      pangeawerks.com.
26.51.31   IN      PTR     pangeawerks.com.

;Your Name Server Info
@               IN      NS      PANGEAVERSE.pangeawerks.com.
PANGEAVERSE     IN      A       72.31.51.26

;Reverse Lookup for your DNS Server
26              IN      PTR     PANGEAVERSE.pangeawerks.com.

;PTR Record IP address to HostName
26              IN      PTR     www.pangeawerks.com.
30              IN      PTR     mail.pangeawerks.com.
```

PANGEAVERSE is the hostname of the server - the FQDN is PANGEAVERSE.pangeawerks.com

Here is the contents of the /etc/hosts file (lots of commenting out of wrong stuff - did not want to get rid of them in case I needed them again or did something wrong):

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.pangeawerks.com PANGEAVERSE
#127.0.0.1      localhost PANGEAVERSE
72.31.51.26     PANGEAVERSE.pangeawerks.com     PANGEAVERSE

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
#72.31.51.26  pangeawerks.com
#72.31.51.26  www.pangeawerks.com
```

Please suggest proper formatting of any of these files, as it's a bit of a hodge podge of other templates.  I am SURE I did something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: "This records must be make on Authority DNS server."  - what does that mean?

Comment: I made those changes and restarted bind9. Now it can ping, but on my mobile phone, the site does not come up if I type pangeawerks.com

Comment: Do I need to reboot the server?

Comment: Nope. DNS must resolve logical name to ip. Give me output from command `dig pangeawerks.com`

Comment: Note the SERVFAIL - how do I resolve this?

Comment: I added what you requested above with proper formatting (i'm brand new at stack exchange - forgive my lack of etiquette).

Comment: @karmacomposer who runs the server your site sits on?  Do you?  If you do, where do you define DNS records through?  A server you maintain or your domain registrar?  Do you have an `/etc/hosts` entry for `www.pangeawerks.com` and not `pangeawerks.com`, or do you use actual DNS?  (I.E. where do you set "this domain points to 1.2.3.4")

Comment: Our own server - right in my office. DNS is through the server.

Comment: We have static IPs and have that set.  I'll post the /etc/hosts above and make corrections if need be

Comment: So should I uncomment out the www.pangeawerks.com and pangeawerks.com entries? Should I comment out the one towards the top?  I am just not sure what's right and what's wrong.  I am soooo rusty at linux.

Comment: @karmacomposer I don't see an /etc/hosts anywhere.  Where'd you put that info?

Comment: I added it to the top - but it's at the bottom of the original edit. Perhaps it's not yet approved - every edit I make says it has to be approved.

Comment: I posted a bunch of stuff - zone files and just about everything else I thought one could use to help me - are you seeing any of it?

Comment: With the help of STEEL DRIVER, I believe we solved the SERVFAIL problem, but I still cannot omit the www to get to our domain's website.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Last comment for today - this is NOT SOLVED. Anyone's help would be immensely appreciated.